# What did Dignam want Billy to tell at Deerfield?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

Dignam asks Billy about Uncle Jackie's funeral:

> Billy: I remember his funeral.
>
> Dignam: Closed casket?
>
> Billy: That's right.
>
> Dignam: **So tell anybody up at Deerfield**... Before you got kicked out
> for whaling on a gym teacher  with a chair. You had an Uncle met his
> demise like that? I got a question. How fucked up are you?

What did Dignam want Billy to tell at Deerfield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking to the full context of the screenplay:

> SGT. DIGNAM (getting to business, hard) You have family connections down in Southie. Through your father. Tell us about your uncle Jackie.

> BILLY Uncle Jackie was a carpet layer for Jordan Marsh.

> SGT. DIGNAM
> Uncle Jackie was a small-time bookie who tended bar at the Vets in
> Somerville. He got popped by Nicastro in '95. They found his body out by the airport.

> BILLY That's right. (tightly) I remember his funeral.

> SGT. DIGNAM (cruelly) Closed casket?

> BILLY That's right.

> SGT. DIGNAM You tell anybody at
> Deerfield - that is, before you got kicked out for whaling on a gym
> teacher with a folding chair - you had an uncle met his demise like
> that?

For more explanation, 'Deerfield' is Deerfield Academy, an upscale prep school where Costigan likely tried to get far away from his family to start a life without stigma like that mentioned of his uncle.

Dignam is asking Costigan sarcastically if he told anyone at this school how 'fucked up' his life really is.